# Force Python (NumPy) to increase CPU usage

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, anaconda

I want to evaluate function `LC.fCore()` for each row of NumPy array `Parameters`. As i understand NumPy has multi-threading, but when i start my code it uses only 10% of CPU. So i should run several instances. Is it possible to force python use almost all CPU? I am working on Anaconda.

**Code**

```
while true:
# get new parameters array ( N rows, 15 columns)
    Parameters=getParameters(N)
    Result=np.apply_along_axis(LC.fCore, 1,Parameters)
    flag=saveResult(Result)
    if flag==0:
       break
```

## Update:

Thanks to @kazemakase (see comments below). But how I may load all cores? I am very new in coding, and in Python especially.

Comment: Are you sure that the apply operation is the bottleneck of you program? This should usually result in using a single CPU completely. Or do you mean by 10% the total of all cores that your computer has?

Comment: Numpy does not multi-thread. Is that 10% of one CPU/core?

Comment: It uses a bit of each core (I have 8). Memory only 22%. I don't use HDD or Network, thus i think the problem is with apply. If NumPy is not multi-thread what should I do? Just now it is pure python code, but on future i wiil make C++ implementation of LC.core().

Comment: If there are 8 cores and one of them runs at 100% load you should see a total load of approximately 100*1/8 = 12.5%. This is very close to the 10% reported in the OP. The operating system usually is smart and distributes work over all avaialable cores. That is why all of them show a bit of load instead of one core running at 100%.

Comment: @kazemakase I've update question. Could you say how I may load all cores in my task.

Comment: You are using `while(true)` followed by `if flag==0: break`. Use `while(flag != 0)` instead!

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Thanks, but it did not solve the problem

Comment: Well it solved one of the problems (bad coding). Now you have one problem less :)

Comment: Seeing LC.fCore as black-box, there is not much you can do besides all the approaches introducing parallel programming. Joblib, Cython, Numba, maybe numexpr and co. (While some primitives are automatically parallel due to BLAS & co, like np.dot, this kind of stuff won't get automatically parallelized imho) (And kazemakase comment on OS-behaviour is correct; let me add, that you should never evaluate your (parallel) performance with looking at cpu-consumption, but benchmarking correctly)